# Blazor wasm failed to start platform. Reason: TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource

Tags: blazor-webassembly

I'm trying to publish my blazor wasm project.  When I hit the url where it is hosted, the app never loads, and I see this error in the console:

```
Error: Failed to start platform. Reason: TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.
    g https://my-test-server.com/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1
    s https://my-test-server.com/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1
    s https://my-test-server.com/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1
    s https://my-test-server.com/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1
    promise callback*u https://my-test-server.com/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1
    a https://my-test-server.com/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1
    promise callback*u https://my-test-server.com/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1
    a https://my-test-server.com/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1
    promise callback*u https://my-test-server.com/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1
    r https://my-test-server.com/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1
    r https://my-test-server.com/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1
    g https://my-test-server.com/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1
    <anonymous> https://my-test-server.com/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1
    n https://my-test-server.com/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1
    <anonymous> https://my-test-server.com/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1
    <anonymous> https://my-test-server.com/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1
blazor.webassembly.js:1:14889
    printErr https://my-test-server.com/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1
    <anonymous> https://my-test-server.com/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1
    (Async: promise callback)
    <anonymous> https://my-test-server.com/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1
    n https://my-test-server.com/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1
    <anonymous> https://my-test-server.com/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1
    <anonymous> https://my-test-server.com/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1
```

This error doesn't really give me much to go on...  Anyone know where I can even start to look to try to figure out what's going on?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I figured it out - it turns out that when I installed .NET 6, publish started to trim assemblies (even though I was using VS2019 to publish).  I had to disable it by adding this to my blazor csproj:

```
   <PropertyGroup>
      <PublishTrimmed>false</PublishTrimmed>
   </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: I had the same error on my webapp. I published some bug fixes last night and the app wouldn't start anymore. You helped me a lot ! Thanks a lot

Comment: @Zeus82 Did you find a solution without disabling `PublishTrimmed`? Because by disabling it, the size of the published file increases drastically

Comment: I haven't really looked into it anymore.  The size for me wasn't an issue.